# CasperJS and MySQL

Tags: mysql, casperjs

I want to save data to a MySQL DB that was retrieved while using casperJS.

I have not been able to find any way to do this directly.

Is there a way to DIRECTLY connect the two?

Will node-mysql work from within Casper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it directly.

You will need to do it indirectly. Remember that CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS which has a different execution environment that node.js. Very few node.js modules actually work inside of PhantomJS/CasperJS without change. You will have to write a script (e.g. node.js script) which has the ability to read a file and write to MySQL.

1. CasperJS script scrapes data and stores the data in some (temporary) file (see [PhantomJS' fs module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/)),
2. Call the external script with the scraped data file (see [PhantomJS' child_process module](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/)) and
3. if necessary, delete the temporary data file either in CasperJS (see PhantomJS' fs module) or the external script.

Comment: Yah, I was thinking I would have to do something similar. Perhaps posting the data to node running express then saving it to db. It's sorta silly you can't use MySQL directly with Casper